# How to define and use a parameter in Jasper Studio that is a set of ids?

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Does anyone know how to define a parameter in Jasper Studio (Community version 6.3.1 final) that is a collection, such as a Set, and to use that in a postgresql query?  For example, this Set could be a set of ids that would then be used in the query.

I do a simple sql query like:

```
select pg_typeof($P{companyDepartmentIds}) as type
```

[image: Picture of parameter that is a set]

I get the following error after selecting "Read Fields":

[image: Error]

It seems like this should be possible, I feel I am missing something. I am not sure where in the Jasper Studio interface I can call this setObject() function.  Anyone have any thoughts here?

If defining a collection of parameters can't be done, the only other thing I could think of is I could have the parameter be a String, but it would be understood it would be a comma delimited list of values, then I could use `regexp_split_to_table` or `regexp_split_to_array` within the query itself.

Comment: You can add field (via button) and set any type you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was directed to this link and saw what I needed here:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-multi-select-query-integer-parameter-japser-ireportstudio

Specifically what I was looking for was this part from the website under the "Correct Way:" example

```
SELECT * from table where $X{IN,id,companyDepartmentIds}
```